# How to open an object with a button which has many properties?

Tags: javascript

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome !</h1>
<p><b>AN OBJECT</b> is also a variable.<b>Thus an object can also be used to store many values.</b></p>
<p id="demo">Click the button given below !</p>
<button type="button" onclick="me()">Click Here !</button>
<script>
function me()
{
 var car ={
 model:"BMW",class:"C",weight:"500",}
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=car.model+"<br>"+car.class+"<br>"+car.weight;
 }
}
</script>
</html>
```

How do I execute the code in such a way that when I press "Click Here !" it is possible for me to see all the properties mentioned in the code ?

Comment: It's not exactly accurate to say that objects are variables.

Comment: Ok ! SO how do I make the above condition possible ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I read that bro ! I trying to make the above code work . But I failed so I posted it here. So that I could find a solution or a hint to solve it ! A small hint will help !

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, extra `}` after the `document.getElement...` statement.

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors. I would suggest you look in the console and review the errors you find.

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks for the correction !

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` in your code. Another way you can do this is that you can pass the `car` object to `me` function from the `onClick` event as you can make that dynamic depending on who the user is.

```
<button type="button" onclick='me({model:"BMW",class:"C",weight:"500"})'>Click Here !</button>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function me(car){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=car.model+"<br>"+car.class+"<br>"+car.weight;
}
</script>
```